# How do I change permissions so I can edit the PAM password file?

Tags: permissions

I am leading a group of students working with Ubuntu 14.04. We need to add password edits, and have been able to type them in, but unable to save due to the file being read only. We have tried to change permissions, but keep getting "operation not permitted."

Help, please :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting `sudo` in front of your command. That said if you are using `gedit` you need to use `gksu gedit` instead of putting sudo in front.

We see occasional questions from students here needing help with their homework projects but this is the first one from a teacher I've seen....

Comment: I am coaching a small group of students for CyberPatriots. We are just starting out and have not received any outside help yet.

Comment: And it looks like the gksu gedit worked! Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. Please remember to click the check mark to show the answer solves the problem such that others know it will work for them too. What are "CyberPatriots"?

Comment: CyberPatriots is an anti-hacking/internet security competition developed by the Air Force. It's gaining in popularity, and my principal asked me to start a team at our school. It's fun, but much is over my head. The kids and I will get better with time. Thanks for your help. That command line stuff is kicking our butt.

Comment: There are lots of great people around here that can help you with any questions. Welcome to AskUbuntu.